# How can I play Dominion by myself (like solitaire)?

Tags: house-rules, dominion, solitaire

Is there any suggested way to modify the rules to play Dominion on your own, like a Dominion Solitaire? It seems possible given that you're mostly just building your own deck and collecting victory points, but I'm not sure how to replicate the scarcity aspect that makes the game competitive and challenging.

Comment: See [this thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/357795/solitaire-easy-rules) for a discussion of one possible game structure.

Comment: Did you find this one on BGG? It's linked through a question much like yours on their forum. https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/415837/soloplay-variant-dominion-now-available

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to make a bot to play against is to not make it have a deck at all, just every other turn make it take a duchy and on the other turns make it randomly take an attack card and do it's effect (only bother with the effect that effects you for the bot doesn't have a deck) 
You should check out the game Ascension, it is a deck building game like dominion, but with a viable built in solitaire variant.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/428919/dominion-solitaire

> I was bored today so I came up with a sort of "Dominion Solitaire".
>
> The way you do it is you set up a standard two player game with you being one player. You simulate the other player's turns in a purely mechanical way, as follows:
>
> Purchase a Province or, if unable to do so, purchase the highest valued treasure you can.
>
> Apart from the randomness in card drawing, you'll be playing a deterministic opponent.
>
> Then see how many points you can beat this "computer" player by.

Comment: Did you copy this from BGG in the sense that you originally wrote it, or are you quoting someone else's idea? Make sure you mark the respective parts as such, and if possible, provide a source link.

Comment: While this would work, the method seems lacking in a few ways. It's uninteresting because in some Kingdoms, Big Money (the strategy described) is the best way to go, while in others, it is hopelessly ineffective. It's uninformative because the point total isn't good way to judge success. It's possible to have a definitive win locked down with only a point or two of margin, but also possible to barely squeak out a win even with a large point margin. It's unnecessary because BM, on average, takes 17 turns to buy 4 Provinces. There's no need to simulate, just use that as a benchmark.

Comment: @NuclearWang "BM on average takes 17 turns to buy 4 Provinces" - only if the opponent(s) never play any attack cards. As soon as you introduce cards like Militia, simulation is necessary.

Comment: @user2390246 If attack cards are in play, BM is almost certainly going to lose to any strategy that employs them. That puts this scenario under the "uninteresting" category. I don't really see the point in simulating a game when you have an >80% chance of winning.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way you could do it is as a strategy test - eg: What's the shortest number of rounds you can reach a pre-determined condition, or highest number of points you can earn in x rounds.

Answer (score 0):

On [Dominion Online](http://dominion.games), you can play a one-player game. It allows you to do all sorts of solitaire challenges.